# AngularJS directive - will the controller always be instantiated before the link function is run?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have an AngularJS directive. Will the controller always be instantiated before the link function is run?

```
function MyController() {}

function MyDirective() {
     return {
         scope: {},
         template: template,
         require: 'ngModel',
         restrict: 'E',
         replace: true,
         controller: myController,
         link: function(scope, element, attrs, controller) {}
     };
}
```

In my tests, the controller is instantiated before the link function is run, but will this always be the case?

**Edit:** based on [this](http://www.bennadel.com/blog/2603-directive-controller-and-link-timing-in-angularjs.htm) post, it looks like the answer is "yes".

Comment: Ben Nadel is right. To fully understand it, you can have a look at this blog post : http://www.jvandemo.com/the-nitty-gritty-of-compile-and-link-functions-inside-angularjs-directives/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, compile is always executed before link. You are looking for this (official):

https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/compiler

If you want to dig further in this, there is another case to know. Link is divided in pre-link and post-link. The order of execution for those is described very well in this blog post:

http://www.jvandemo.com/the-nitty-gritty-of-compile-and-link-functions-inside-angularjs-directives/